# Bash Shell Systax error on comm and diff commands

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to use "comm" to compare 2 files and save whatever the difference between them is in a third file, like the example below.

```
if [ -e "$updated_file_name_$day$month$year.txt"];
then
    comm -3 < (sort $updated_file_name".txt") < (sort $updated_file_name_$day$month$year.txt) > $updated_file_name_$day$month$year_V$i.txt
else
    mv $updated_file_name".txt" $updated_file_name_$day$month$year.txt
fi
```

It searches or the previous version of a file, if it finds it than both files are supposed to be sorted and compared, than the result would be saved in a third file, else it just saves the new file as the original file for that date.

I used it on the shell console as "bash -c 'comm -3 [rest of the command]" and it worked but for whatever reason it isn't working on my script, i always get the wrong syntax error.

I also tried using "diff instead of "comm" but i get the same, i don`t know what the problem is.

Here is the error message:

```
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `diff < (sort $updated_file_name".txt") < (sort $updated_file_name"_"$day$month$year.txt) > $updated_file_name"_"$day$month$year_V$i".txt"'
```

Comment: What says the error message ?

Comment: The question is updated.

Comment: i believe process substitution is without spaces. maybe `<(command)` instead of `< (command)` ?

Comment: ill test this right now

Comment: how is this comm or diff related? (it's a rhetorical question...)

Comment: You have numerous syntactic issues; please check your code with http://shellcheck.net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things to address here,

1. `<()`, *process-substitution* is a `bash` feature, you proabably need to run it with a proper she-bang set i.e. `#!/bin/bash` or depending upon your distro, where `bash` is installed
2. There should be no-spaces present, i.e. using `comm -3 <(sort $updated_file_name".txt") <(sort $updated_file_name_$day$month$year.txt)` is the correct approach.

---

Another OP's question was `sort` was unable to open the file, getting errors during it.

Recommend, properly encasing the variables within `{}`

```
comm -3 <(sort ${updated_file_name}".txt") <(sort ${updated_file_name}_${day}${month}${year}".txt")
```

Comment: Here is another question. The comm command is executed but for whatever reason it is not getting my variable as file names. Im getting errors like the following:
sort: open failed: _.txt: No such file or directory

I also cant use the comm command out using  "bash -c" before it.

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man: Refer my update in the last, to see if that solves your problem

Comment: Well, i'm still getting following error message:
sort: open failed: _.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man: Well do ask it as a new question with the details, it is not longer int the scope of the current question.